# AWS Glue locally - No module named 'awsglue'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, wsl-2

I installed each prerequisites according to `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-python` and still getting `No module named 'awsglue'` error.

- AWS Glue version 3.0,
- Apache Maven from the following location: `https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-common/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz`
- AWS Glue version 3.0: `https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-3.0/spark-3.1.1-amzn-0-bin-3.2.1-amzn-3.tgz`
- SPARK_HOME is setup
- ran `glue-setup.sh` from `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\my_user\aws_ds\glue_libs\aws-glue-libs\bin`
- when I run `spark-shell` or `pyspark`, both are working fine

Please help on debbuging this as I don't know where to start else.

Comment: Are you using one of the utility scripts it says to use for python?

Comment: Yes, sample python script I wrote is placed in the `aws-glue-libs` folder and now import seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

1. Make sure your Glue script is ran in the `aws-glue-libs` folder
2. Sync jar files between `jarsv1` in `aws-glue-libs` and `jars` in `your_spark_folder` (`quava` jar may have two versions, leave latest one)

Installation steps to consider

3. Get Spark on WSL2: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-ubuntu
4. Remember to run `glue-setup.sh` from `aws-glue-libs\bin` as a last step of [Setting up Glue locally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html?fbclid=IwAR1W7HHsqlHUIg_Ic-SfV1IdnxaIllR2yTQOb5DS8zzdMXffYnB1PWCMRMA#develop-local-python)